# Open an Access 2007 database in a shared network folder from a button on another database

Tags: ms-access, vba

Can someone please point me in the right direction, or know of a way to open an Access2007 database file housed on a network shared drive, from a button within another Access2007 Database which is also saved to the same network shared drive, just a different folder? I.E. I have Datebase2.accdb saved to a shared network drive folder, I've created a button on frm_dashboard of Database1.accdb and no matter what I do I cannot get the button to open Database2 from the shared drive folder. I even tried setting the hyper-link to the file as someone suggested and that won't open Database2 either. Macros seem to only set the on open event from within the current database you have open. I haven't been able to find VBA to do this either.

Comment: My apologies, yes that is correct. I am trying to get Database2 to open in a new Access application and run along side of Database1. Users would need to have access to both applications concurrently.  Thank you Hans

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new Access application session and open your other database in that session.

This is the Click event procedure for a command button named *cmdOtherDb*:

```vb
Private Sub cmdOtherDb_Click()
    Dim objAccess As Access.Application
    Dim strPath As String
    strPath = "C:\share\Access\Northwind_2007.accdb" ' <-- change this
    Set objAccess = New Access.Application
    objAccess.UserControl = True
    objAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase strPath
    Set objAccess = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Private Sub btnSMBDashboard_Click()      -Dim objAccess As Access.Application      -Dim strPath As String      -strPath = "\\snt200\SMB Database_Mod\Dev\SMB_Dev1.2.accdb"      -Set objAccess = New Access.Application      -objAccess.UserControl = True  
    -objAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase strPath      -Set objAccess = Nothing  End Sub  1st thank you! This does open a new application of Access, however it throws an error "Microsoft Office Access can't open the database because it's missing, or opened exclusively by another, user, or it's not an ADP file." And i'm not sure why? @Hans

Comment: First thing I'd check is whether *strPath* is correct.  Does `Dir(strPath)` show you the file name or an empty string?

Comment: I swear I formatted that reply correctly :) ... strPath does show the filename so I'm not sure why it won't open it. @Hans

Comment: Comments only support minimal formatting.  But don't worry about that.  Since the db file exists, next investigate whether it's open already --- is there a lock file (SMB_Dev1.2.lccdb) present in that folder?

Comment: No sir! This is a database I'm creating that no one has access to until I roll it out. There are no lock files present. It acts like it is going to open, which really excited me, but then it hangs at that error. @Hans

Comment: Rats!  The last issue in your error message mentions ADP and I have no clue why it would complain that your db is not an ADP.  I wonder if only that particular db is problematic.  I suggest you create a new empty db file, place it in that shared folder, change *strPath* to point to it, and see whether the code opens it successfully.

Comment: Same error! I'm starting to think this may be an issue with having access to the shared drive that i'm going to have to investigate! Where I work we have to obtain access at all different levels so that's the only thing remaining I can think that would be the issue. None the less you have pointed me in the perfect direction so again THANK YOU! @Hans

Comment: Try the code with a db file in a folder where you are guaranteed full access ... like *C:\Users\shaun\Documents*.  It just *has* to work then ... dammit!

Comment: That's exactly the issue, moved the file to a local folder and changed the path and YAHTZEE! Thank you again very much! @hans

Comment: Woot!  You did what I suggested before I completed typing the suggestion!  Congrats.  Now fix your share privileges and you should be golden.  :-)

Comment: Yessir!!! Working on that now! Thank you again that was driving me insane!!!! @Hans